# How to open a modal popup extender with a gridview

Tags: gridview, modalpopupextender, ajax.net

I want to open a Ajax ModalPopup extender control which contains a gridview.I searched thro Google, but I couldnt find a proper solution. Can anyone send me a sample codebase for opening gridview in Ajax ModalPopup extender control.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you implemented this thing or i explain that how to implement it??

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/05/07/using-the-modal-popup-extender-to-build-a-popup-search-interface.aspx Read above article...you will find good solution.....

Answer (score 0):

place the grid you want to show in the panel

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />       
     <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender_PreReq" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPrereq"
                        CancelControlID="Button_Close" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrereq" runat="server" Style="display: none">
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Close" runat="server" Text="Close" />         
 </asp:Panel>
```

In any event you can call this.Modalpopupid.show(); to display the grid view in modalpopup